# Host Keys updated unexpectedly

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

This morning autossh failed to connect to a server. I looked at the logs and saw that seemingly the server's fingerprint has changed and thus, the connection could not be established.

I then logged in on another terminal and accepted the new fingerprint and eventually figured out that all `ssh_host_*_key` files were updated at exactly 3am this morning. This is the time when the server rebooted to complete unattended updates.

Why would these keys be automatically rotated?

Some things that might be helpful:

- The only updated packages in the last two weeks (all yesterday) were `linux-oracle-headers-5.15.0-1052:all`, `linux-headers-5.15.0-1052-oracle:amd64`, `linux-modules-5.15.0-1052-oracle:amd64`, `linux-image-5.15.0-1052-oracle:amd64` `linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1052-oracle:amd64`. All of them updated from version `5.15.0-1051`.
- There was no ssh login for about 4 weeks according to the welcome message.
- The `authorized_keys` look good.
- The old host keys were from April 2021.

Comment: I found a documentation which appears to link the use of a (virtual) serial console access and the rotation of the SSH host keys: "The server host keys are periodically rotated for security purposes.". Are you in this case? https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/serialconsole.htm#Connecti2__keys . Or maybe this rotation is done whatever the context (iaas or not, serial or not...)?

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the pointer! The server is actually running at Oracle (thus also the oracle kernel packages). However according to the support, this was not the case here, even though the chat agent did not seem very confident. So this might be the cause, given that there is no other answer yet...